# Calculating and presenting relative values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having problems making a graph in ggplot2.

I measured on different days the emission rate of different compounds from organic and mineral soils. I have a dataset consisting of these six columns: `soil`, `soil_type`, `compound`, `group`, `rate`, `day`.
The compounds are grouped into three groups: `CxHyOz`, `CxHy`, `mz<137`.

I now wish to present the "relative emission rate" (e.g each group's contribution to the total emission) of each group, for organic and mineral soils on each day measured. Like the graph below, but with only two columns: organic and mineral (In the graph below there are also some additional compound groups, but this does not matter).

[image]

I come up with the code below, but it doesn't work.

```
df_relative_values <- df %>% 
  group_by(soil_type, group, day) %>% 
  summarise(sum_rate=sum(rate)) %>% 
  group_by(day, soil_type) %>% 
  mutate(sum_soil=sum(sum_rate)) %>% 
  mutate(rel_soil=sum_rate/sum_soil)
 

stackedbars_plot <- df_relative_values %>% 
    ggplot()+
    geom_bar(aes(x=soil_type,  
                 y=rel_soil, 
                 fill = factor(group, levels=c("CxHyOz", "CxHy", "mz<137"))),
                 stat="identity")+
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdYlBu") +
    labs(x = "Incubation", y = "Emission", title = "BVOC emissions", fill = 
           "group") +
    facet_wrap(vars(day),
               scale="free_x")+
    tidytext::scale_x_reordered(expand = c(0,0)) +
    scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0))+
    theme_bw() + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.4), axis.text=element_text(size=5))
)
```

The data looks like this:

```
df <- structure(list(soil = c(31L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 31L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 31L, 
2L, 1L, 5L, 31L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 31L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 31L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
31L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 31L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 31L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 31L, 2L, 1L, 
5L, 31L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 31L, 2L, 1L, 5L), soil_type = c("organic", 
"mineral", "mineral", "organic", "organic", "mineral", "mineral", 
"organic", "organic", "mineral", "mineral", "organic", "organic", 
"mineral", "mineral", "organic", "organic", "mineral", "mineral", 
"organic", "organic", "mineral", "mineral", "organic", "organic", 
"mineral", "mineral", "organic", "organic", "mineral", "mineral", 
"organic", "organic", "mineral", "mineral", "organic", "organic", 
"mineral", "mineral", "organic", "organic", "mineral", "mineral", 
"organic", "organic", "mineral", "mineral", "organic"), day = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), rate = c(65, 18345, 52173, 0, 135, 22452, 
47584, 32, 4, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 39, 3, 11, 93, 49, 
12, 21601, 1772162, 3468591, 2082, 2795, 3069533, 3396515, 2720, 
1, 1, 35, 2, 2, 15, 28, 4, 0, 18, 2, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2), group = c("mz<137", 
"mz<137", "mz<137", "mz<137", "mz<137", "mz<137", "mz<137", "mz<137", 
"mz<137", "mz<137", "mz<137", "mz<137", "mz<137", "mz<137", "mz<137", 
"mz<137", "CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", 
"CxHy", "CxHyOz", "CxHyOz", "CxHyOz", "CxHyOz", "CxHyOz", "CxHyOz", 
"CxHyOz", "CxHyOz", "CxHyOz", "CxHyOz", "CxHyOz", "CxHyOz", "CxHyOz", 
"CxHyOz", "CxHyOz", "CxHyOz", "CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", 
"CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy", "CxHy"), compound = c(33.031, 33.031, 33.031, 
33.031, 33.031, 33.031, 33.031, 33.031, 36.017, 36.017, 36.017, 
36.017, 36.017, 36.017, 36.017, 36.017, 40.023, 40.023, 40.023, 
40.023, 40.023, 40.023, 40.023, 40.023, 45.03, 45.03, 45.03, 
45.03, 45.03, 45.03, 45.03, 45.03, 49.024, 49.024, 49.024, 49.024, 
49.024, 49.024, 49.024, 49.024, 68.055, 68.055, 68.055, 68.055, 
68.055, 68.055, 68.055, 68.055)), row.names = c(NA, -48L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any suggestions as how to make this work is much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: There is no `rel_soil` variable in your example data. What column should go on the y-axis?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @teunbrand. I have edited the code a bit. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for updating the code, but now there is no `days_incubated` column. Sorry for nagging!

Comment: Thanks again @teunbrand. Maybe it's correct now...

Comment: Doesn't the code work now? Granted, CxHyOz dominates the graph, but it seems to work.

Comment: How did you expect the output to be different from what you got? What doesn't work about it?

Comment: You're absolutely correct @dyrland. It turns out that the problem was not with the code, but the fact that my university automatically installed an older version of R on my PC. Two active versions of R on my pc has caused the software to act weird in a number of instances. Now I've uninstalled the old version and coding is smooth again. So sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Yay it works! Huzzah!